# How many cores for SSIS?

Tags: performance, ssis

I did a proof of concept for a complex transformation in SSIS. I have performance metrics now for this POC that I created in a virtual machine, with 1 gig memory, 1 core assigned. The SSIS transformations are all file based (source and target).

Now I want to use this metric for choosing the right amount of cores and memory in production environment.

What would be the right strategy to determine the right amount of cores and memory for production if I know the amount of files per day and the total amount of file size per day to be transformed ?

(edit) Think about total transfer sizes of 100 gigabyte and 5000 files per day!

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to do two other benchmarks: 2 GB mem, 1 core and 1 GB mem, dual core. Taking a snapshot of a fairly tiny environment is difficult to extrapolate without a couple more datapoints.

Also, with only 1GB RAM you'll also want to make sure the server isn't also running out of memory and paging to disk (which will skew your figures somewhat as everything becomes reliant on disk access - and given you're already reading from disk anyway...). So make sure you know what's happening there as well.

SSIS tries to buffer as much as it can in memory for speed, so more memory is always good :-) The bigger question is what benefit extra cores will give you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of areas for performance.  One is the number of cores.  The more cores you have the more parallel work that can be done.  This of course is also dependent upon how you build your package.  Certain objects are synchronous others are asynchronous.  Memory is also a factor, but it is limited to 100MB/dataflow component.

Comment: Can you explain why there is a limit of 100mb/dataflow component ? Do you have any reference that state this ?

Comment: Please note that the memory used by component is limited only for synchronous (streaming) components. Asynchronous (sort, aggregate, etc) may consume more memory.